# Easiest way to execute a command line python script from a webpage

Tags: python, web, python-2.7

I have a python script that works from the command line. Instead of people running the script from command line and knowing which parameters go where I would like them to go to a webpage and select options and then run the script from the webpage. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? If you have complete control of the app, just build it using some python web framework (like Django), import the script and invoke it (you may have to refactor it a bit).

Comment: Take a look at the wsgi plugin for whatever webserver you are running.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using CGI plugin for your webserver that handles python scripts.

Comment: My webserver is currently running on localhost can you please explain how I would set it up to call the python script

Comment: which webserver is it? @Siecje

Comment: @Siecje then see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799354/configure-apache-to-use-python-just-like-cgi-php . especially the answer by JimB