# python program not executing at the server end

Tags: php, python, cgi

my python program is not executing at the server end and instead when i press the submit buttonthe browser is displaying the raw code of my python file.

I have kept my file in the  path var/www/webgui.py.

I have installed apache web server.

please help on this.

Comment: If you don't post your code or log traces... How do you think that someone could help you ?

Comment: Is the apache web server actually running during this process. You know you have to manually turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Apache thinks your python file is a file to be served, and not a script to run. You need to configure apache to tell it how to treat the python files.  There are a number of ways of doing this.

See here [Configure Apache to use Python just like CGI PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799354/configure-apache-to-use-python-just-like-cgi-php) and http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Essentially you have to configure an extension that allows apache to run python scripts. mod_python and mod_wsgi are two examples (you only need one).

Comment: I tried som stuff like adding the below code in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default                                                 AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
PythonDebug On       but still it is not working,it is still retrnin g the raw code.please help on this as i am new to python....